# Passing Login Details to React Native WebView

Tags: react-native, webview, react-native-webview

I'm trying to pass login details to a WebView, basically, my use case is, I have a login page built with React Native, after a successful login I wanted to redirect the user to a WebView login with the login details so the WebView doesn't render the login page in itself. So, to achieve this I attach the ref to webView like so

```
<WebView ref={webViewRef} ... />
```

With the login page built with ReactNative, the user will enter their credentials, once the login is successful I'll get the user details from the backend as a response to the LOGIN Post API Call, so I passed the response to the `postMessage` function

```
const response = await LOGIN({...credentials});
webviewRef.current.postMessage(response.data);
```

And to the React Web app, I used the below code to add the listener

```
window.addEventListener("message", (message) => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(message.data));
});
```

But, I'm not getting the data with `message.data`.

Any workaround would highly be appreciated

Comment: Hi @Haider., I need a small clarification. You mentioned that you are not getting the data with message.data. So is the window.addEventListener callback being called when the webviewRef.current.postMessage executes and message.data is undefined or is the eventlistner not completely being called?

Comment: @Gavara.Suneel Thank you for your response, eventListener is getting called but the data is undefined

Comment: please check my answer below. https://stackoverflow.com/a/75337444/8988448

Comment: are you able to solve the issue with the approach suggested by me?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `injectJavaScript` method on the webviewRef to send data from the app to the web(i.e., to react side). The post message will be used vice-versa i.e., to send data from react side to the app side. The solution below would solve your issue.

First on react side, set the custom function on the window object.

```
window.onUserLogin = function(userDetails) {
     alert(`userDetails are ${JSON.stringify(userDetails)}`)
}
```

Now on the react-native side, you have the `webViewRef`. Using that please make the below call.

```
const USER_DETAILS = {
    userName: "Haider"
};  
 webViewRef.current.injectJavaScript(`window.onUserLogin(${JSON.stringfy(USER_DETAILS)});true;`)
```

Comment: It says that `injectJavaScript` is not a function, then I passed a prop `injectedJavaScript={window.onUserLogin(${JSON.stringfy(user)});true;}` it says that onUserLogin is not a function

Comment: @HaiderNaseer., No need to send injectJavaScript as a prop. This would be part of webViewRef.current. See the code below

import WebView from 'react-native-webview';
import React, {  createRef } from 'react'
function SampleComponent() {
 const webViewRef = createRef();
   
  useEffect(() => {
    const USER_DETAILS = {
    userName: "Haider"
   };  
webViewRef.current.injectJavaScript(`window.onUserLogin(${JSON.stringfy(USER_DETAILS)});true;`)
  }, [webViewRef])

 return <WebView ref={webViewRef} />
}

Comment: It saying that `ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property injectJavaScript of undefined`

Comment: Oh. This is an issue with webViewRef. Please make sure you correctly configure webViewRef because as per the error, webViewRef.current is undefined. Two possible reasons are either you are misconfiguring webViewRef or you are making injectJavaScript call on webViewRef even before it is instantiated.

Comment: Okay, for mobile app part, it is working fine now with `webViewRef.current.injectJavaScript("window.onUserLogin(${JSON.stringfy(USER_DETAILS)});true;")`.. But. on the react frontend there's no impact of the calling function `window.onUserLogin = function(userDetails) {
     alert("userDetails are ${JSON.stringify(userDetails)}")
}`

Comment: @Haider, Please register the function on the web side when the page loads. Please check whether there is a function with `window.onUserLogin` existing or not. You have to keep this function at the top level of your JS code so that it would be immediately loaded and available for native.